# How to set responsive width and height of canvas?

Tags: html, css, chart.js

When I use CSS in the container holding the canvas, I get the desired height and width. But when I minimize it, it is not responsive.

```
.lineGraph{
    height: 100%;
    width: 52%;
    background-color: white;

}
```

***Desired size:***
[image]

***When minimized:***

[image]

But when I put the CSS on the canvas itself, it becomes responsive when minimized. But I do not get the desired size of the chart when it is maximized.

```
#lineChart{
    height: 100%;
    width: 52%;
    background-color: white;

}
```

***When maximized:***
[image]

***Responsive when minimized: ***

[image]

How can I get the desired size when maximized but get a responsive output when it is minimized?

Answer (score 0):

Add a div around your chartjs or canvas:

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
    <canvas id="mychart" "width="600" height="250"></canvas>
</div>
```

Add height to the wrapper, and adjust it according to responsive redering

```
.chart-wrapper {
height: 300px !important;
}
```

Comment: the .lineGraph is the div around my canvas

Comment: Okay you can give a height to that div and adjust it according to change in screen size

Comment: As stated above, I already gave it height and width. Should I not use percent (%)? Should I use px instead?

Comment: Try using px and while you resize if its broken use media queries to adjust it

Comment: Angel could you please post some proper code you are using ([reprex]), because now you have us only guessing what the problem might be.